# Timeout termintation XCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

My algorithm is to time heavy due to data length (fastest possible for such data).

I want to turn off timeout termination of project.
Is it possible?

P.S.

put an endless loop in

-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application { }

to see what kind of termination I mean.

AND

It's must be in Delegate and it must me in applicationDidFinishLaunching.
Just need a few more seconds to complete(NSLog says 2000 records when it terminates - I have 2500).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer.
The simplest way to do such thing is creating a new thread.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(your method) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:false];
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot increase or disable that timeout.

As a solution run your heavy algorithm on background thread and present user with intermediate screen showing that your application actually performs some task and not just hanging..

Comment: The reason for this is because when the main thread is blocked, the app is unresponsive.  Unresponsive apps suck.

Comment: You mean: like button touching or just after view Load?